# How to split a String in Java, ignoring multiple successive tokens

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to parse arguments for a command, but if I were to put multiple spaces in a row, String.split() will leave empty Strings in the result array. Is there a way I can get rid of this?

For example: `"abc     123".split(" ")` results in `{"abc", "", "", "", "", "123"}` but what I really want is `{"abc", "123"}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use [regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
"abc   123".split("\\s+");
```

Here `\s` is any whitespace character and `\s+` is one or more consecutive whitespace characters.